# Verilog array element assignment

Tags: arrays, verilog

I am trying to learn Verilog (first module that i'm trying to implement is 7 segment display driver), and i have problem with array element assignment not working. Would this be a valid use of array in verilog?

```
reg [6:0] digits_7seg [0:10];
reg [6:0] segmap;

initial begin
 digits_7seg[0] = 7'b1111110;
 digits_7seg[1] = 7'b0110000;
 digits_7seg[2] = 7'b1101101;
 digits_7seg[3] = 7'b1111001;
 digits_7seg[4] = 7'b0110011;
 digits_7seg[5] = 7'b1011011;
 digits_7seg[6] = 7'b1011111;
 digits_7seg[7] = 7'b1110000;
 digits_7seg[8] = 7'b1111111;
 digits_7seg[9] = 7'b1111011;
end
```

*somewhere later in `always @(posedge refresh_clk_in)` block:*

```
segmap = digits_7seg[ones_in];
```

The problem is that assignment of array element to segmap register seems to fail. For example, if i try:

```
segmap = digits_7seg[1];
```

I get nothing on the display (segmap seems to contain `7'b0000000` ). But if i'll use direct bitmap assignment like:

```
segmap = 7'b0110000;
```

then appropriate segments are turned on on the display (displaying digit 1). What can be wrong with this simple array element assignment?

Comment: the code in your example looks correct. You did not provide the rest of your  code, so it is difficult to figure out what is going wrong. So, the first question: is the `refresh_clk_in` clock toggling? if it does not, no assignment could be done. As a side note, if you use edges in the always block, also use the non-blocking assighment `<=`.

Comment: Here's entire module: [https://github.com/woytekm/verilog-excerise-1/blob/master/display_driver.v](https://github.com/woytekm/verilog-excerise-1/blob/master/display_driver.v)

Comment: Few facts about the module: I want to to drive 4 digit 7 seg display. If i use nonblocking assignments in `always @` section - it doesn't work (some random segments flash every few seconds, but that's it). Module is clocked by 2Mhz PLL, and the clock is there for sure (checked with oscilloscope). If i use blocking assignments and i assign bitmap directly to `segmap` - static digits are displayed properly on the display. If i use array assignment (as in first `case` statement) - this digit is blank.

Comment: Regarding blocking and non blocking assignments - basically i need assigments in `always @` block to happen in order: first, i load value from  input, then i need to get appropriate array element using this value as an array index, then i need to drive common cathode for this digit down, to activate display. Is there a way to do this in one block using non blocking assigments, or should i split it all into dfferent, separately clocked blocks? What would be the best practice here?

Comment: From your code I see that you are trying to perform combinational logic in an always block sensitive to a clock edge. Try replacing `always @ (posedge refresh_clk_in)` with `always @ (*)` to infer a combinational logic.

Comment: Also, you would need to split the sequential (freq_divider counter) and combinational logic into different procedural blocks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no code in your module which toggles clocks. Either you have to instantiate it from another module which does it or add something like the following to your code:

```
always 
    #1 refresh_clk_in = ~refresh_clk_in;
```

do not forget to exit the simulation after a number of simulation cycles or on some condition.

About non-blocking assignment. It is an industry wide practice to use non-blocking assignments on all **outputs** of the edged-triggered always blocks. You'd better do it right from the beginning. You do not need to do it on intermediate results though.

Answer (score 0):

"Regarding blocking and non blocking assignments - basically i need assigments in always @ block to happen in order: first, i load value from input, then i need to get appropriate array element using this value as an array index, then i need to drive common cathode for this digit down, to activate display. Is there a way to do this in one block using non blocking assigments, or should i split it all into dfferent, separately clocked blocks? What would be the best practice here?"

You just defined a sequential logic design. Having non-blocking statements would not be the right way to handle this. 
I'm not sure about the specifics you are targeting, but it looks like you would need a finite state machine. 
Have the design progress each step clock after clock.

Have all sequential logic written in one always block. This should be sensitive to a clock and a reset. Have all combinational logic written in a separate always block.

Read the input in the first clock cycle, decode it in the second and drive it in the third. 
See if your design allows pipelining.